# PHP Script for last login time

Tags: php

I've got this script to update a table in my database with the logout time of a user, then when they log in next time, this data is shown in the form of "Last login: date time".

However this isnt working, and was hoping for some help.

Posted in `functions.php`

```
function userloginvarset($login){
    global $user_ID;
    global $userlogininfo;
    $userlogininfo = get_user_by('login',$login);
}
add_action('wp_login','userloginvarset');

function last_login($login) {
    update_usermeta($userlogininfo->ID, 'last_login', current_time('mysql'));
}

add_action('wp_logout','last_login');

function get_last_login($user_id) {
    $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', true);
    $date_format = get_option('date_format') . ' ' . get_option('time_format');
    $the_last_login = mysql2date($date_format, $last_login, false);
    echo $the_last_login;
}
```

and
Posted in `page.php`

```
global $userdata;
get_currentuserinfo();

echo('Welcome '.$userdata->display_name.'!</br>');
_e('Last login:');
get_last_login($userdata->ID);
```

the displaying of the data works fine, its just the updating of the table. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Sidenote: Please properly indent your code, it is hard to read and to debug :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

After a lot of research I found the way to hook into logout and get user data, and as i was looking for that i found the exact answer i was looking for.

```
function users_last_login() {
    $cur_login = current_time('mysql');
    $userinfo = wp_get_current_user();
    update_user_meta( $userinfo->ID, 'last_login', $cur_login );
}
add_action('clear_auth_cookie', 'users_last_login', 10);
```

Thanks for the help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You second function, last_login references the $userloginfo variable which is not within the function's scope.

Try the following:

```
function last_login($login) {
  global $userlogininfo;
  update_usermeta($userlogininfo->ID, 'last_login', current_time('mysql'));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt help :/ It still didnt update the data with the time of logout :( Thanks for your help :)